# Reverse engineering a BLE device : invisible service UUID & characteristics

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, reverse-engineering

I want to reverse-engineer the bluetooth BLE controler of my ebike, so I can control it with an iOS app.

I have read many tutorials and so far, I have successfully sniffed BLE packets that flow between my iPhone and the controler, using an app called PacketLogger.

But what I get from sniffing is quite confusing :

[PacketLogger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X52e6.png)

Here, you can see the BLE data that flow when I'm turning the bike headlamp on (filtered on the correct device ID).

There doesn't seem to be any details on the services, no UUID and no characteristics.

When I connect to the ebike controler and scan for its services / characteristics, I see that :

[iPhone screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGYcK.png)

[iPhone screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljlNy.png)

[iPhone screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfVJm.png)

[iPhone screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4L0b.png)

I don't recognize any of the attributes that where previously sniffed...

What do I miss ? Is there something I forgot ? :/

Comment: You need to determine which attribute was mapped to the Attribute handle during the connection process.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 
I sniffed the packets during the connection process, in order to find the attribute mapping.
Here is the result : https://imgur.com/a/iM5a6BW
I found this "Attribute List" line, but I don't find any known attribute mapping in it...

Comment: Hi @VincentDecharonne, were you successful with this topic? Thanks

Comment: Hi @BradAdams, I wasn't successful but I am back on this topic now after 1,5y of pause ^^

Comment: @VincentDecharonne any news on this?^^